# Advanced Pricing for Shopware 6 (KeyValuePair Type error)

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to update product price with custom rule (advanced price) programmatically in Shopware 6 
I have the following array

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "productNumber" => "Test1"
    "prices" => array:4 [
      "ruleId" => "cfda4784f29b40428c881e3a1878ad69"
      "quantityStart" => 1
      "price" => array:1 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "currencyId" => "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca"
          "gross" => 2.0
          "net" => 1.0
          "linked" => true
        ]
      ]
    ]
    //This is the product ID
    "id" => "dc00dd078e4949bc9aadb14e62cf6924"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "productNumber" => "Test2"
    "prices" => array:4 [
      "ruleId" => "cfda4784f29b40428c881e3a1878ad69"
      "quantityStart" => 1
      "price" => array:1 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "currencyId" => "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca"
          "gross" => 2.0
          "net" => 1.0
          "linked" => true
        ]
      ]
    ]
    //This is the product ID
    "id" => "2324be8b90a54524914b86bc8f0521e4"
  ]
]
```

As soon as I run the custom CLI command, I get this error:

```
 [TypeError]
  Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\DataStack\KeyValuePair::__construct(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type string, int given, cal
  led in /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Write/DataStack/DataStack.php on line 47
```

I’ve tried to insert to product_price table instead of updating the product. Same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

`prices` has to be a list containing associative arrays.

```php
[
    // ...
    'prices' => [
        [
            'ruleId' => 'cfda4784f29b40428c881e3a1878ad69',
            'quantityStart' => 1,
            'price' => [
                [
                    'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
                    'gross' => 2.0,
                    'net' => 1.0,
                    'linked' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```